# When I use setMetadataObjectTypes: to load the type of the scanning barcode, I would like to set severals types (code39, code128, etc...)

Tags: ios, camera, barcode, scanning

I wrote this code for my app that uses the camera to scan barcodes:

```
[captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code/\*AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code\*/]];
```

I would like to know how it is possible to write the fact that the `setMetadataObjectTypes` can handle two types of barcode: the barcodes code39 and code128?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I finally found the good way to write it :

```
        [captureMetadataOutput 
         setMetadataObjectTypes:
         @[AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code]
];
```

or

```
    [captureMetadataOutput
     setMetadataObjectTypes:
     [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
      AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code, 
      AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code,
     nil]];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's exactly how you do it. Can you accept your answer?